# Function expects structure of newtype but not newtype itself

Tags: haskell, types

I seem to miss something fundamental.

When I try to map join with the `sampleGraph` I get this error:

```
Main> map join sampleGraph 

<interactive>:3:10:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘[(Start, [End])]’
            with actual type ‘Graph’
    In the second argument of ‘map’, namely ‘sampleGraph’
    In the expression: map join sampleGraph
```

**This is the code**

```
type Node = Integer
type Edge = (Node,Node)
type Start = Node
type End = Node
newtype Graph = Graph [(Start,[End])] deriving (Eq,Show)

join :: (Start, [End]) -> [Edge]
join (start, ends) = map (\ e -> if start < e then (start, e) else (e, start)) ends

sampleGraph = (Graph
    [(5,[1,2,3]),
     (7,[1,2]),
     (1,[1,2]),
     (2,[1,2])
    ])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of map is

```hs
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

In this case, join has type

```hs
join :: (Start, [End]) -> [Edge]
```

So `map join` has type

```hs
map join :: [(Start, [End])] -> [[Edge]]
```

And what we want is `Graph -> [[Edge]]`. So we need a function `Graph -> [(Start, [End])]` and we'll be all set. Fortunately, this is really simple with record accessors!

```hs
type Node = Integer
type Edge = (Node, Node)
type Start = Node
type End = Node

newtype Graph = Graph {
  edges :: [(Start, [End])]
} deriving (Eq, Show)

join :: (Start, [End]) -> [Edge]
join (start, ends) = map (\e -> if start < e then (start, e) else (e, start)) ends

sampleGraph =
  Graph [(5, [1, 2, 3]),
         (7, [1, 2]),
         (1, [1, 2]),
         (2, [1, 2])
        ]

foo = map join . edges
```

We declare an accessor `edges` for the edges field, and it's automatically given the type `Graph -> (Start, [End])`. Composing `map join . edges` yields the final desired type.

An alternate way of doing this would be to use a case-expression to destruct `Graph` into its constituent parts:

```hs
case sampleGraph of
   Graph edges -> map join edges
```

Life is a buffet of options.

Comment: typo: it should say "we need a function Graph -> [(Start, [End])]"